# Key error when using .pivot in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have looked at lots of pivot table related questions and found none that addressed this specific problem. I have a data frame like this:

```
Drug        Timepoint    Tumor Volume (mm3)
Capomulin   0             45.000000
            5             44.266086
            10            43.084291
            15            42.064317
            20            40.716325
... ... ...
Zoniferol   25            55.432935
            30            57.713531
            35            60.089372
            40            62.916692
            45            65.960888
```

I am trying to pivot the data so that the name of the drug becomes the column headings, timepoint becomes the new index, and the tumor volume is the value. Everything I have looked up online tells me to use:

```
mean_tumor_volume_gp.pivot(index = "Timepoint",
                           columns = "Drug",
                           values = "Tumor Volume (mm3)")
```

However, when I run this cell, I get the error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-788b92ba981e> in <module>
      2 mean_tumor_volume_gp.pivot(index = "Timepoint",
      3                             columns = "Drug",
----> 4                             values = "Tumor Volume (mm3)")
      5 

KeyError: 'Timepoint'
```

How is this a key error? The key "Timepoint" is a column in the original DF.

Comment: You're missing the commas between the function arguments

Comment: Putting in the commas just gives me a KeyError: 'Timepoint'

Comment: @jason-hernandez-73 your pivot code looks totally legit. I think you should reset_index your initial data-frame. so you'll have Drug as index.